# using spark to read file from hdfs

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs

I've the code below which reads files from my local drive however I want it to read the files from a folder on hdfs. I'd like to use sc.textfile method however I'm a bit stuck initialising it correctly. could you please help?

```
session = SparkSession.builder.appName('myapp')
session = session.master ('local').getOrCreate()
sql_context = SQLContext(session.SparkContext)
sql_context.sql("SET spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1")
cwd=os.getcwd()

names=session.read.csv(os.path.join (cwd, 'local/path/to/file'),    header=True, inferSchema=True).repartition(nameid)
classes=session.read.csv(os.path.join (cwd, 'local/path/to/file'),    header=True, inferSchema=True).repartition(classid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not continue with session / spark?

```
df_load = sparkSession.read.csv('hdfs://cluster/user/hdfs/test/*.csv')
```

Comment: if I do that then do I replace my code names=session.read.csv(os.path.join (cwd, 'local/path/to/file'),    header=True, inferSchema with anything

Comment: yes, you can adapt and do regex pattern matching, different directories. I use spark but you have session variable, cool.

Comment: Did this help by any chance?